# I cannot clone with git clone error: connection refused

Tags: git

I am trying to clone my repository. But I get this error shown below.

```
git clone https://github.com/amanmyrats/taksi
    Cloning into 'taksi'...
    fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/amanmyrats/taksi/': Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 1080: Connection refused
```

I usually use psiphon VPN, since github is blocked. sometimes it is not.

Now my vpn is off. I am using company computer
I already tried to unset http.proxy.

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
git config --global --unset https.proxy
```

Still get same error, and interestingly it says Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 1080???

if it helps there is one strange thing that I could not understand, when I list my remotes I got this list, even after I unset http.proxy globally

```
git config --global -l
    http.schannelcheckrevoke=false
    http.sslverify=false
    http.sslcainfo=C:\Users\a.soyunjaliyev\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\mingw64\ssl\cert.pem
    remote.taksist5.proxy=
    remote.origin.proxy=
    remote.origin.proxy=127.0.0.1:1080
    remote.origin.proxy=127.0.0.1:1080
    remote.origin.proxy=127.0.0.1:1080
    gui.recentrepo=D:/bckup Aman/coding/taksi-aws/tt
```

May be it is using remote.origin's proxy(probably), but how to avoid that one?
Any help of yours is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe there's a `HTTPS_PROXY` environment variable that you might need to get rid of.

Comment: check `git config -l` without global, just to be sure you dont have it configured on a different level

Comment: I checked environmental variables, there is no HTTPS_PROXY in it. And checked git config -l as well, http.proxy is empty like this: credential.helper=manager
http.proxy=
https.proxy=
http.schannelcheckrevoke=false

Comment: What I don't get it that why it says me this: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 1080. this address is only in [remote.origin.proxy=127.0.0.1:1080]. It looks like it is making me trouble. How can I get rid of that? any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: I reinstall git, did not help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your settings:

```
remote.origin.proxy=
remote.origin.proxy=127.0.0.1:1080
remote.origin.proxy=127.0.0.1:1080
remote.origin.proxy=127.0.0.1:1080
```

tell your Git to connect to port 1080 on 127.0.0.1 (your own machine) in order to reach github.com.  Clearly you want to get rid of that for now.

The fact that the setting shows up four times (three with a value, one without) means you have more than one entry for this.  You'll need to remove all of them, or set them all to empty (though there's no point in having redundant settings).

If all of them were in the *local* configuration, you could use:

```
git config --unset-all remote.origin.proxy
```

to remove all of them from the local configuration.

Since the ones you showed are all in the *global* configuration, you will need:

```
git config --global --unset-all remote.origin.proxy
```

to remove those.

If some are set elsewhere, you may need more than one `git config` command to unset them all.

The command `git config --list --show-origin` will show all settings and show where each one comes from.

Answer (score 1):

I cloned with super user permission (`sudo`), it worked for me:

```
sudo git clone ...
```