# git clone fails with error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80

Tags: javascript, node.js, isomorphic-git

I'm using isomorphic-git for a project, and when attempting to use `git.clone` I get the error `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80`.

This is a simple reproduction of what I'm trying to do:

```js
import * as git from 'isomorphic-git';
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as http from 'http';
const git_options = {
    fs,
    http,
    dir: config.git_dir, //yes this is defined
};

const remote_repo = 'dr-vortex/blankstorm';

await git.clone({ ...git_options, url: `https://github.com/${remote_repo}.git` });
```

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66599325) question using canonical git and checked the config with isomorphic-git and none of the values are set.

After navigating to the repository destination I found a complete git repository without a working tree. Doing a `git pull` fixes everything.

I also tried setting the ref option on the config (in case it was trying to pull the non-existant master branch, since I use main)

Is there a way to fix the error so that a git pull is not necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node.js' `http` isn't a supported HTTP client. You have to use an HTTP client that implements the documented interface: https://isomorphic-git.org/docs/en/http

`isomorphic-git` provides two HTTP clients. You can use the provided Node.js HTTP client:

```
import * as git from 'isomorphic-git';
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as http from 'isomorphic-git/http/node/index.js';
const git_options = {
    fs,
    http,
    dir: config.git_dir, //yes this is defined
};

const remote_repo = 'dr-vortex/blankstorm';

await git.clone({ ...git_options, url: `https://github.com/${remote_repo}.git` });
```

Comment: Thanks! After seeing the part with `fs` I assumed it would be the same for http.